# Can an oracle SQL query execute a string query selected from a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

When using oracle SQL is it possible to run a query based on a text_string from a subquery?
An example might clarify what I'm trying to do

```
    select count(sql_text), sql_text
    from
        (select sql_text 
        from query_table) sql_table
    group by sql_text;
```

The outer query is intended to count the number of results for each query retrieved from the query_table.

Is there some way I can execute the sql statements I retrieved from my query_table in the same query?

Thanks

EDIT:
   I was able to query sql from a table using the dbms_xmlgen.get_xml() function.  I suppose that any command which caused the sql to be parsed and executed would work.
That being said, here's the generic code that I was able to accomplish things with:

```
    select  to_number (
        extractvalue(
        xmltype(
        dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '|| table_name)), '/ROWSET/ROW/C'))counter,
        sql_text
    from
        (select '('||sql_text||')' table_name 
        from query_table) sql_table;
```

While perhaps not the most elegant way to do things, it works and is a single sql statement.

Comment: Don't think you can do it this way, may be in PL/SQL

Comment: Why don't you first call the inner query and then make the main query from your code?

Comment: @Bozorgzadeh  I'm trying to create a view out of the results to remove a bunch of manual coding in a legacy system

Comment: man, this helped me a lot, your answer was what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, this isn't a particularly good design-- storing SQL in tables and dynamically executing it introduces all sorts of security and maintenance issues.

It is probably possible (though it's way too late on a Friday that started way too early for me to try to figure it out) to do a really cool XML query along the lines of [this query that runs a count(*) against every table in the schema](http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2007/04/how-do-i-store-the-counts-of-all-tables.html) that would do this all in one query.

For the vast majority of programmers, though, the simpler approach would be to loop over the queries, run them one at a time, and store the results somewhere.  Potentially the local variable would be added to a collection of counts, for example.

```
FOR q IN (SELECT sql_text FROM query_table)
LOOP
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (' || q.sql_text || ')'
     INTO some_local_variable;
  <<do something with the local variable>>
END LOOP;
```

Since you're trying to create a view, you could take this logic and put it in a pipelined table function.  You'd do a `PIPE ROW` to return data within the loop.  Your view could then be created on top of the pipelined table function.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it showed me that there were functions that could execute my sql and return the values.  As for "pipelining", I haven't yet ventured into that conceptual area.  Sounds like something I'll need to do sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 1):

Going through Basics..

When the database executes an `SQL`
1) It would first do `SEMANTIC` check by validating the *syntax* and the *objects* (tables and columns used) in SQL.
2) Based on it, the `optimizer` draws a `PLAN`(calculating the indexes to be used, with the available table statistics and histograms)..
3) And the `SQL Engine` executes the Query as per the *PLAN*.

So, all these means, the SQL cannot do dynamic object referings.. Since it needs to study all the elements in SQL before execution itself.

Hence, unfortunately, your requirement is *NOT* possible with a simple SQL solution.

`PL/SQL` or some other Database specific special tools.. is what you have to opt for.

Comment: A concise, clear and direct answer - Thank you.  You were right that a more complex sql solution would be required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in PL/SQL, it can look like this (if I understand your requirement properly):

```
create table sql_commands (cmd varchar2(1000));
insert into sql_commands values ('select * from table_1');
insert into sql_commands values ('select * from table_2');
commit;

declare
begin
   for aLine in (select cmd from sql_commands) loop
      execute immediate aLine.cmd into ... -- depends on your command
   end loop;
end;
```