# Execute the SQL statements from table within an Oracle SQL procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm a newbie in PL/SQL and I'm struggling with following issue. I'm looking for an answer for 4 hours and it's still not working...

I've got above 300 records in a table with SQL statements and **my goal** is to write a **procedure** that is able to loop over them under some conditions.
I'd like also to check which queries passed and which ones failed.

So it goes like this (list of steps/pseudocode):

- procedure or function that takes a *condition* as a parameter
- iterates over records that match a *condition*
- executes SQL statements which fit match
- gives an information of success or failure of execution

I was trying to do something like this (below) but I think it's not correct - because I'm not looping over records.

```
DECLARE
   sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(3000);

BEGIN
   sql_stmt := 'SELECT testcase_sql
                FROM data_audit_testcase_v2
                WHERE testcase_desc LIKE ''Test 6 - EM%''';
   dbms_output.put_line('Sth: ' || sql_stmt);
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt ;
END;
```

I'm thinking about adjusting this code to my issue:

```
FOR q IN (SELECT sql_text FROM query_table)
LOOP
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (' || q.sql_text || ')'
     INTO some_local_variable;
  <<do something with the local variable>>
END LOOP;
```

[source here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636887/can-an-oracle-sql-query-execute-a-string-query-selected-from-a-table)

What do you guys think?

Thank you for your help in advance,

Arthur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like this:

```
DECLARE
   sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(3000);
    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    some_local_variable data_audit_testcase_v2.testcase_sql%TYPE;
BEGIN
   sql_stmt := 'SELECT testcase_sql
                FROM data_audit_testcase_v2
                WHERE testcase_desc LIKE :val';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Sth: ' || sql_stmt);
    OPEN cur FOR sql_stmt USING 'Test 6 - EM%';
    LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO some_local_variable;     
        EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
        <<do something with the local variable>>
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you @Wernfried for your contribution.  
But I'm still not able to check if the query was executed. I tried to add sth like
    `DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cur);`  
to see **what's in a current step** of the loop, but it doesn't compile without warnings and doesn't work for me.  
Can I ask you for help?

Comment: Make `DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(some_local_variable);`

Comment: in line `FETCH cur INTO some_local_varbiable;` I'm getting an error: `Inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s` (it's ORA-06512). I'm trying to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: It seems `PUT_LINE` can't print neither `some_local_varbiale` nor `cur`

Comment: I've found the solution - I added second parameter to the SELECT, so PUT_LINE didn't know how to display it :).

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution - I added second parameter to the SELECT, so PUT_LINE didn't know how to display it :).