# Executing data validation rules from a table using a procedure with runtime values

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a table that is filled with many data validation queries. For example a row:

```
SELECT end_time - start_time 
FROM mt_process_status 
WHERE process_id = <PROCESS_ID> AND ref_date = <REF_DATE>
```

I have to execute all these SQL statements filling the values within '<>' with run time values and check if the performance of the process has not changed.

Can this be done with a stored procedure? I want to understand what the solution would look like.  Any links to documentation of this sort of thing, anything to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: So does this wonderous table have a column telling you how many placeholders each string has and what they're supposed to be?

Comment: You're missing some information, but the answer to your question seems to be 'Yes'. Not sue that's very helpful though. Were you hoping someone would write the procedure for you?

Comment: @APC: it doesnt actually.. but i can create one for all the rules..

Comment: @AlexPoole: I was wondering how it would work architecture wise.. can a stored procedure take this data validation SQL from this table, fill it with parameters and run it on tables of my choice?

Comment: Sure, with dynamic SQL. As long as all the information is available and you know how to replace each placeholder. This is a very broad question though.

Comment: [Something like this might get you started](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21637219/266304).

Comment: @AlexPoole: thanks alex.. at what point would I have to replace the placeholder? lets say i want to find out the processing time.. sort it into red, green and yellow flags for all the thousands of tables in my database.. how would i go about running the procedure?

Comment: Really not sure what you want to do. Perhaps you should flesh out your question with more details of the process you're trying to implement. Although I agree with Alex that this is rather a broad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere there's a bunch of analysts in your organization telling each other, "We've done the difficult stuff, we've defined the queries. All the database has to do is execute them, how hard can that be?" Answer: very hard.

Let's take the query you posted:

```
select end_time - start_time  from mt_process_status where process_id = <PROCESS_ID> AND ref_date = <REF_DATE>
```

It's easy enough to use `replace(the_str, '<PROCESS_ID>', 1234)` to substitute a value. But for `ref_date` that's presumably a date, so it needs to be `replace(the_str, '<REF_DATE>', 'date ''2017-01-01''')`. Starting to get icky, and that's just handling literals. It will be even ickier when the substitution values are passed as parameters.

Of course I've made an assumption that PROCESS_ID is numeric. Maybe it isn't. Who can tell? Is there a data dictionary where these details are defined?

It would be easier if the query was defined with dynamic SQL placeholders:

```
select end_time - start_time  from mt_process_status where process_id = :PROCESS_ID AND ref_date = :REF_DATE
```

Then you could forget about the replace and simply run

```
 execute immediate the_str 
     using 1234, date '2017-01-01' 
     into whatever;
```

But you still need to know how many placeholders there are, in what order they occur and what datatype they are. It may feel like this is soft-coded and configurable but there is still a really hard dependency between the query and the program which calls it.

Plus you have lost the ability to do impact analysis. What queries will be affected when you change `mt_process_status`? Who can tell?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROC(g_id)
AS
l_query varchar2(1000);
l_duration number;

BEGIN
-- Get the query from the table
select query into l_query from my_table where id=g_id;

-- l_query contains "select end_time - start_time from mt_process_status where process_id = <PROCESS_ID> and ref_date = <REF_DATE>"

-- Put value to replace the tags (take care of code injection...)
l_query := REPLACE(l_query,'<PROCESS_ID>', something);
l_query := REPLACE(l_query,'<REF_DATE>', something_else);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lquery RETURN INTO l_duration;

-- Do what you have to do...
-- If you do a function, then you can:
-- RETURN l_duration;

END;
/
```

Your question is not clear. This is the answer to your question. Use variables in a procedure.

regards.

Comment: Thanks a lot first of all for taking time in writing that.. how would i fill the 'something' and 'something_else'.. Can I pass it off as parameters for the stored procedure? What if I want to run this for thousands of tables and check the processing time for each table.. how would that work?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the reference data in another table and do it as a join