# Pivot an unknown field value

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot

I'm running Oracle 11.
I have a table of customers references `shorto04` with documents to be printed. There are many type of documents and I don't know them all in advance.

Here is an example of data:

| shorto04 | wdocname |
| --- | --- |
| 7739096 | SL00A |
| 7739096 | TR00A |
| 7740767 | AV00BITA |
| 7768159 | SL00AFRA |
| 7768159 | TR00AFRA |
| 7768159 | AD00AFRA |
| 7768159 | PL00AFRA |
| 7771629 | SL00A |
| 7780966 | TR00A |
| 7780966 | AD00A |
| 7812187 | SL00A |
| 7812187 | TR00A |
| 7812187 | AD00A |
| 7817697 | SL00AGBR |
| 7817697 | TR00AGBR |
| 7817697 | AV00BGBR |
| 7818401 | SL00AGBR |
| 7818401 | TR00AGBR |
| 7818412 | SL00AGBR |
| 7818412 | TR00AGBR |
| 7829375 | SL00AGBR |
| 7829375 | TR00AGBR |
| 7829375 | PL00AGBR |
| 7832296 | SL00A |
| 7832296 | TR00A |
| 7832296 | AD00A |
| 7832297 | SL00A |
| 7832297 | TR00A |
| 7832297 | AD00A |
| 7840205 | OD00IGBR |
| 7840205 | SL00DGBR |
| 7840205 | AV00DGBR |

Boss asked to count all different types and how many we have.
So I started with a query like the belolw:

```
Select *
from 
(
select shorto04, SUBSTR(wdocname, 1,5) as docs
 from O04T91
)
pivot
(
count(docs)
for docs in ( 'TR00A' , 'OD00A')  
)
```

of course my sql result is far from what I need:

| ShortO04 | tr00a_ | od00a_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7709902 | 1,000000 | 0,000000 |
| 7725337 | 1,000000 | 0,000000 |
| 7729012 | 1,000000 | 0,000000 |
| 7729062 | 1,000000 | 0,000000 |
| 7739096 | 1,000000 | 0,000000 |
| 7740767 | 1,000000 | 1,000000 |
| 7768159 | 1,000000 | 0,000000 |
| 7771629 | 1,000000 | 0,000000 |

with my method I'd need to hardcode in the query all possible document types and if there will be any new ones they will not be counted.

here is an example of a partial expected result:

| ShortO04 | tr00a | od00a | ad00a | av00b | sl00a | od00i | av00d | etc | etc | etc | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7709902 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7725337 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7729012 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7729062 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7739096 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7740767 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7768159 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7771629 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7780966 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7812187 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7817697 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7818401 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7818412 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7829375 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7832296 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7832297 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 7840205 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |
| 7840228 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL, or pivot in an external reporting tool; but would that output really be useful? Does the requirement to "count all different types and how many we have" actually mean "for each shorto04", or do you only really want the total across all customers?

Comment: this is just the core of the query, I'm adding the customer name etc as they request different documents fo the same type (i.e. 3 label types when just 1 is needed and allowed by our policy... and so on). This will end up in an action to our customers. Take shorto04=7740767 as example, "tr" and "od" are two labels, system prints both and worker staple just one and throw the other.

Comment: OK, but if you had that pivot result you wouldn't be able to do anything further with it, without more dynamic SQL, as an outer query would also need to know the column names. I think you might need to rethink your approach...

Answer (score 1):

You can select distinct values via

```
select distinct wdocname
from shorto04;
```

And generate your query like this:

```
SELECT 
    'SELECT Shorto04, ' ||
    LISTAGG(
      '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDREF tmp  WHERE tmp.shorto04 = ORDREF.shorto04 and wdocname = ''' ||
      wdocname ||
      ''') AS ' ||
      wdocname ||
      ' FROM ORDREF GROUP BY Shorto04;'
    , ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY wdocname) AS query
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT wdocname
    FROM ORDREF
) t;

SELECT Shorto04,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDREF tmp WHERE tmp.shorto04 = ORDREF.shorto04 and wdocname = 'OD00A') AS OD00A,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDREF tmp WHERE tmp.shorto04 = ORDREF.shorto04 and wdocname = 'TR00A') AS TR00A
FROM ORDREF
GROUP BY Shorto04;
```

Basically, you add the main column, then the subselects in a comma-separated manner having the distinct `wdocname` as the input. The query was untested. If you create a SQL Fiddle with sample data, I'm happy to test it more practically.

EDIT

Since a SQL Fiddle was provided, I was able to test the query in practice and I have adjusted the query to work in practice. Already updated it above.

Fiddle link: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd7e3/1

The first query, the one shared in this answer generates the query to be actually executed as a text. Oracle is capable to execute a text as query, see: [Can an oracle SQL query execute a string query selected from a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636887/can-an-oracle-sql-query-execute-a-string-query-selected-from-a-table)

Comment: here is my first try with SQL Fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72d450/1

Comment: This looks like untested code. If you had tested it you would have found that there are syntax errors from missing commas, too many commas in other places and then when you fix those you would have found that `CONCAT` only takes 2 arguments.

Comment: @MT0 it is indeed untested code, as I clarified in the answer because there was no input to work on. Since Emare has sent a Fiddle, I plan to look into it and adjust the code.

Comment: @emare thanks for the fiddle. Fixed the code accordingly, please take a look both here in the answer and the link I have given.

Comment: @MT0 edited my answer so now the code is correct, given the fact that we have a proper input now.

Comment: @LajosArpad thanks for your effort, actually I was looking a way not to enter all possible `wdocname` values in the `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDREF.......`. I have to figure out how `xmlserialize` works and put it in my query. So far I did not succeeded :(

Comment: @emare is `xmlserialize` a field?